# SQL Developer Table View not showing tables

Tags: database

I have an Oracle login with which to connect to a remote Oracle db.
I am using jdbc thin driver.
After a successful connection, my navigation view does not display the table I have access to.
However, I am able to do a select on a table I have access to.

I tried a few other db tools, like Navicat, Aqua, and the db tool in Eclipse, but same problem.
What would make the tables not show up in a db tool?

Comment: won't show if the tables are not owned by my id, will see via sysadm schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to look at correct user, admin

Comment: Should be more explicit with this answer, though.  What you mean to tell people is that, in Oracle, it will only show you tables that belong to *schemas* (databases in MS SQL Server) that are owned by that account.  The owner will be who will see those tables under "Tables" in the tree.  If you do not, you have to go under "Other Users" and expand each user until you find out who created/owns that schema!  So counter-intuitive! It will not matter if your account has permissions to the tables or not, you still have to go under that user that owns it to find it!